# HDIV with Richfaces 4

Tags: richfaces, hdiv

I am using [HDIV](http://hdiv.org) with JSF I want to add Richfaces to my application but the use of rich components like calender results HDIV exception since those components creates client side elements which are not part of JSF component tree. How can I aproach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably Know RichFaces is not supported by HDIV. In order to solve the problem the are two possible solutions:

- Define the new client side parameters as start parameters. In that case HDIV is not going to validate them but it will work. It seems they are editable parameters so maybe is enough.
- Extend the RichFaces component in order to register the parameters within JSF tree. This solution could work but takes much more work.

Comment: thanks for the response. I want to override org.hdiv.validators.RequestParameterValidator#validate so i can handle the extra validations.